# Register as versioned with move edits to base - when not to?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, versioning

What limitations do I get, when I chose to register as versioned with the option to move edits to base?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are tradeoffs. I don't use this option because it limits the ability to create "check-out replicas" (show stopper for me). Another limitation when you chose this option is that you can't edit feature classes that participate in a topology.

Many people use this option because they need to support third party (non-ESRI) applications. When edits are made to the DEFAULT version that is registered with the option of 'move edits to base', those edits are immediately moved to the base tables rather than being stored in delta tables and requiring a sync operation... This is usually the only way that a third party application can interact with a versioned geodatabase.

[ESRI Help Topic is here.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Data_maintenance_strategies/003n000000t4000000/)

Answer (score -1):

My SDE guru friend told me that if you allow move edits to base directly, there is no control or useful operations like undo or redo.What if sth bad happens ... Hopefully your database is backed up.