# Undo option to 'move edits to base' ArcSDE

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I have an ArcSDE Geodatabase where a number of layers are registered as versioned. Having spent some time troubleshooting an issue I'm having with syncing data on Collector, I have noticed that the layers which are not loading are those which are registered as versioned with the option to move edits to base.  I suspect this is my problem and I am looking for a way to remove the option easily.

Presumably, if I reconcile and post all changes to the DEFAULT version, then unregister as versioned, then register as versioned again (being careful not to tick the box with the move edits to base) this will solve my issue without losing any data? If I do this, will it be applied to all feature classes or can I specify the ones I want to unregister?

Is this a viable option or are there better ones? What are the risks?

Answer (score 1):

The option **move edits to base** basically means that all your edits are not written to the delta-tables but to the actual business-table. Therefor undo- and redo-operations are not possible.

If you unregister any dataset (can be specified for any dataset seperately) as unversioned all your edits within those delta-tables are dropped whereby it is not recommended to do this as long as you have ongoing edits that have not been posted to default. Therefor you should make a compress before on the base-tables unregistering as versioned to prevent data-loss.

Anyway the option **move edits to base** is ment to be used for third-party-tools that cannot access the delta-tables and therefor the versioning-system. I´d recommend to not do this.

EDIT: I assume that currently all your edits actually go to the base-tables as the option is currently enabled. Registering the table as versioned without the option should therefor work withoutr any problems as the delta-tables are not used currently and therefoir no ongoing edits are available. This there should be no loss of data if you uncheck the option.

You might also have a look on [Register as versioned with move edits to base - when not to?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34717/register-as-versioned-with-move-edits-to-base-when-not-to)

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. When you register a dataset as versioned you get the DEFAULT version and the ability to undo during an edit session. The option simply determines where the edits go that are saved to DEFAULT. If on, they go into the base tables. If off, they remain in DEFAULT. Note that you can still create child versions from DEFAULT but the base tables wont see those changes until they are posted to DEFAULT (With the option on).